# create-react-app won't load local images dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to dynamically load multiple images with create-react-app.  I am not able to see the images on the page.  This is what I see.  [image: This is what I see when checking the page]Here is my code.

Gallery.js

```
export default [
 './images/urban_pocket_park.jpg',
 './images/urban_pocket_park(2).jpg',
 './images/urban_pocket_park(3).jpg',
 './images/urban_pocket_park(4).jpg',
 './images/urban_pocket_park(5).jpg',
 './images/urban_pocket_park(6).jpg'
]
```

UrbanInfo.js

```
import Gallery from './Gallery'

const UrbanInfo = (props) => {

 const images = Gallery.map(function(image, idx) {
  return (
   <Image key={idx} src={image} />
  )
 });

 return (
    <div>
      {images}
    </div>
 )
}
export default UrbanInfo;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.  I have checked the path of the images and they work fine.

Comment: What links do you see when inspecting the image tags?

Comment: I see.  <img class="nskosj" src="./images/urban_pocket_park.jpg">.  Basically what is in my Gallery.js file.

Comment: You cannot add images to comments.

Comment: I just realized that.

Comment: as far as i know you need to `import` (or `require` if its dynamic) in order to include the images in your bundle.js (or extract them to your build folder)

Comment: How about `images/` instead of `./images/`?

Comment: The problem I see might be with your image path. I tried it with different image paths and it works well [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zxztxz)

Comment: Or `/images` - and @Sag1v no, when they are saved inside the public folder

Comment: @Andy it didn't work.

Comment: inside your `map` function, try doing `const img = require(image)` and then `<Image key={idx} src={img} />`

Comment: @thomasna82 where did you save your images?

Comment: @lumio did he say they are saved?

Comment: src/components/images

Comment: Shouldn't the images be in the `public/images` folder? And then the path `/images/...` should load them correctly. That's how I've used create-react-app at least. What you're trying to do isn't "dynamic loading" btw, from how I understand your question, that's actually quite static since you're just rendering `<img>` tags.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: @timotgl that worked.  TY.

Comment: @timotgl okay thanks.  You are correct.